# Button does not contain a definiton for ID

Tags: c#, button, sender

This is my `Form1.cs` file. The method should display by a `MessageBox` the clicked button's ID, but I get this error.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button button = sender as Button;
            string buttonId = button.ID;
            MessageBox.Show(buttonId);
        }
```

Error:

> 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension
>   method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Website or a Windows Application?

Comment: Did you use the correct namespace?

Comment: It is a Windows Application.

Comment: I want to mention that I'm new in C#.

Comment: You don't have property called ID in windows Form application. Take a look at this link for the properties of Button class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could I get the button's number using `TabIndex`?

Comment: The `Tag` property can be used for arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows Forms application, then the built in `Button` controls do not have a property called `ID`. You probably want to fetch the `Name` property, which is unique for each button control.

A quick example:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    string buttonName = button.Name; //Button does not have an ID - use Name instead
    MessageBox.Show(buttonName);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But I want to get the button's order number.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by order number? You could try using the `button.TabIndex` property, but this value is not unique for each button.

Comment: So, when I click the `button1`, I want to get number 1. When I click `button2`, number 2 and so on...

Comment: I set the same method for every button. I have ~140 buttons.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use the `Name` property, as this is unique for every button, and then name the buttons appropriately to get them in the order you need. Alternatively you could save an ID in the `Tag` property of the buttons, but again you have no guarantee that this value is unique.

Comment: @Alex Did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: I put my buttons in a certain order, and I used `TabIndex` to get the button's number. It works for me, even isn't the most efficient way.